# Saving Excel workbook on a local network location

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a workbook on a local network drive location. the code is working fine, the only thing is, an alert shows up showing file being saved and the network path is shown on the same.

```
Public Sub Test(sFileLocation As String, sFileName As String)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim bDisplayAlerts As Boolean
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
bDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts

If fso.FolderExists(sFileLocation) Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'some operations        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close True, sFileLocation & sFileName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bDisplayAlerts
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to save a workbook on a local network drive location. the code is working fine, the only thing is, an alert shows up showing file being saved and the network path is shown on the same.

Comment: yes, that will happen when your network is slow. there is no way to get rid of that.

Comment: get rid of the stuff after `wb.Close True`

Comment: @cyboashu: is there a work around to upload a file to a local network drive then.